# need to cancel a long running query on sql server

Tags: sql-server

I've been running a delete query on one of our databases. The query has been running for about 7 hours and now I need to cancel it. If I cancel it will it cause a rollback? And of so, is there a way to cancel the query without causing a rollback?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I cancel it will it cause a rollback?

Yes, and it likely takes longer than it was running so far.

> nd of so, is there a way to cancel the query without causing a rollback?

No. The data now is in an inconsistent state without rollback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will cause a rollback. You can expect the rollback to take even more time than the original delete (because a: rollbacks are always single-threaded and b: rollbacks are logged as well). Same if you restart the instance. SQL Server will always do it's best to return database to transactionally consistent state.

To add to my own answer :)
The best way to delete large amount of data from a table is to do it in smaller chunks, like 5000 rows at a time, each in it's own transaction. I know it's too late now, but for the next time.
Unless you're deleting all the rows from the table, then it's TRUNCATE TABLE the fastest method.